# influence of oversampling on Semi-supervised multi-label learning

Tags: multilabel, semi-supervised-learning, oversampling

I have suggested a semi-supervised approach for the hierarchical multi-label classification task.
I have included the MLSMOTE oversampling technique as a pre-processing step, and then evaluate the impact of the oversampling on the semi-supervised learning 
Below, the obtained results in terms of Micro-f1 and Macro-f1 scores.

[image]
[image]

These two figures are under the labeling ratio 50% labeled, 50% unlabeled.

My question is, is it possible to say that oversampling is beneficial at the end 
 of co-training, because at the last iteration, we get the same Macro-F1 scores, we obtain higher Micro-F1 scores for the method without oversampling ? the reason could be that the latter is biased towards the majority labels which increases the Micro-f1 scores in detriment of Macro-F1 scores.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Since there are no posted answers to your question, you may delete it (see our [help center article](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question). However, do not vandalize your questions. Be aware that when you posted content on SE, you gave up the ownership of that content under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/licensing).